mysql server replicate to aws redshift thorugh aws dms
I am getting this error in AWS DMS while replicating the dataenter image description hereenter image description here
Error output:-

Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider  ODBC general error., Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 1130 Message: [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Host 'ip-172-31-46-60.eu-west-2.compute.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

this error was fixed but in task during migration single table is also giving same error in temp task
I have tried to provide the role permission.Thanks in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you are using rds mysql look into redshift zeroetl, it’s free and basically managed dms
